# Saving Arrays to and retrieving from Parse in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, parse-platform

My app contains WordLists with associated Words in CoreData. I can upload them to Parse to share them, but i am struggling to get them out from Parse again and back into CoreData.

To save all the words associated to a wordlist to parse I have:

```
parseWordList.setObject("\(wordList?.words?.valueForKey("wordName"))", forKey: "Words")
```

which saves as a string, but looks like a set in Parse which has confused me?

[image]

Then when I query the list again I am struggling to covert to an array so I can iterate through it and save it back into CoreData.

How do I convert the Parse Words string/set? back to an array, and how do I get rid of the 'Optional' prefix when saving to Parse?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me...

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "WordList")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && objects != nil {
                for object in objects! {

                    let joinedWords = object.objectForKey("Words")
                    let joinedWordsArray = Array(arrayLiteral: joinedWords)

                    let wordEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Word", inManagedObjectContext: self.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext)

                    for joinedWord in joinedWordsArray {
                        let word = Word(entity: wordEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext)
                        word.wordName = joinedWord as? String
                        word.wordList = joinedWordList
    }
                }
        } else {
            print("Error")
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: you're still getting the description of the set, so it saves as a string - just stop using the description...

Comment: `how do I get rid of the 'Optional' prefix` By learning Swift. :) Optionals are a key concept. A good start here: [The Swift Programming Language, The Basics: Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)

Comment: hi again Wain - are you saying I should use valueForKey instead?

Comment: Hi Eric - I am aware of why one needs Optionals, what I don't understand is how Parse stores them. When I want the value of an object in parse I just want the value as a string - same as I put in, not the fact that it is an optional written and appended to the string itself...

Comment: Hi Wain - what code do I need to stop using the description?

Comment: `what I don't understand is how Parse stores them` It's a false problem: you just have to **not** save Optionals! Unwrap your values before saving, don't ever save an Optional String, make it an actual String first. That's what I meant with my initial comment.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Got it now. inching forwards!

Answer (score 0):

instead of:
    let joinedWordsArray = Array(arrayLiteral: joinedWords)

try 
    let joinedWordsArray = joinedWords as! Array

hope this helps

Comment: hi - that gives an error "Generic parameter 'Element' could not be inferred".